# albd service is not starting in Windows

Tags: clearcase

Facing error 1067 for when trying to deliver into integration stream.

On investigation, it was found that `albd` service isn't coming up.
Have checked out the doc regarding this error code on IBM, none of the resolutions have helped.
What could be the possible cause?

Errors faced :

```
 cleartool: Error: Unable to contact albd_server on host 'hostname'
 albd_contact call failed: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = [WINSOCK] 
 Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this when the ClearCase license server itself was down.

But if this is not the case here, check the Windows Event viewer for more clues on that particular instance, for example right after attempting to start the albd service.

Comment: The logs say -  cccredmgr : error contacting aldb server

Comment: @What version of Windows 10, and of ClearCase are you using? What kind of view are you using (snapshot, dynamic, or CCRC one like webview, automatic)?

Comment: WIndows 8, CC - 7.0.1, snapshot views

Comment: @Shivani CC 7?! I did not know it was still around. Does the issue persists with a dynamic view? Are all services started on your Windows (as shown in the "ClearCase Control Panel": https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/start-and-stop-clearcase-windows-command-line)

Comment: Except the albd service, all are running

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is the local host or a remote one. If the local host, this technote may help: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/troubleshooting-albd-startup-failures-microsoft-windows

If a remote host, that technote may still apply, but you may also be dealing with a network issue. Some questions may help clarify the issue in that case:

- Does the issue impact multiple clients?
- When did this start?
- Are there any functions that work from this host? ("Cleartool quit" command, cleartool lsvob, etc.)

Comment: I have tried each workaround mentioned in the doc, nothing has helped